# MySQL community server 8.0.18 conflicts with ODBC connector 5.1

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to connect to MySQL server 8.0.18.0 using an older MySQL 5.1.36 ODBC connector?

Comment: If you use a retocompatibility password yes

Comment: Is the retocompatibility password yes available from the command line.

Comment: why not upgrade your ODBC connector?